# stability of a negative charge in halogens and that of orbitals

Tags: orbitals

when we talk about stability of halogen anions we say,
$\ce{I-} \gt \ce{Br-} \gt \ce{Cl-} \gt \ce{F-}$, and the reason is that "the negative charge (the electrons) have more space to move about in the larger halogen". But when we talk about stability of a negative charge on an orbital, why do we say that the negative charge on the $sp$ hybridized orbital (which is the smaller one) is more stable than $sp^2$ and then $sp^3$ as the least stable where as the  $sp^3$ orbital is the biggest orbital among all of the three and can allow the electrons to spread out more.

Comment: The primary stability factor is energy. Also, what do you mean by stability, particularly what do you mean saying I- is more stable than F- ? It is easy to oxidize I-, but try it (chemically) with F-.

Comment: I meant that the iodine anion is more stable than the flourine anion, as there is much more space for the electron density to spread out in iodine anion. @Poutnik

Comment: No, that is considered reason of stability, not what you mean by stability itself. Do you mean hydrated or naked ion ? Do you mean acido-basic stability or general chemical stability ? You have put too little context in the question, what usually leads to unnecessary clarification ping-pong.

Comment: oh that was a question on checking which compound was more acidic

Comment: and that has not been included in the question, because.......    ?  For the basicity of hydrated halogenides part, or acidity of hydrated hydrogen halogenides,  it is much more complex, as the environment interaction and thermodynamics has to be considered. See https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Modules_and_Websites_(Inorganic_Chemistry)/Descriptive_Chemistry/Elements_Organized_by_Block/2_p-Block_Elements/Group_17%3A_The_Halogens/1Group_17%3A_General_Reactions/The_Acidity_of_the_Hydrogen_Halides

Comment: hmm my bad for not including it, thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

When we talk about hybrid orbitals and stability of charge on them, the electronegativity factor plays a more prominent role. The *sp* hybridised orbital is more electronegative than the others, owing to Bent’s rule which states - **Greater the s character of a hybrid orbital, greater is its electronegativity.**

Therefore, species having the negative charge on an *sp* hybridised atom tend to be less basic.

(You might be interested in knowing that, an *sp* hybridised carbon atom is actually more electronegative than a nitrogen atom.)

Comment: Looking at the other comments, I also get suggestions that there may be a slight confusion between basicity and nucleophilicity. Basicity is a characteristic property, and that depends only on how stable the negative charge on an atom is. Nucleophilicity is, however, dependent on a few other things besides that. It’s not a characteristic property, it’s more like a kinetic property.  They do go hand in hand sometimes, but not always.

Comment: In the context of my previous comment, for example - the iodide ion is a weaker base than the fluoride ion. And that won’t change no matter what environment (solvent) you want to test their basicities in. But, the iodide ion happens to be a stronger nucleophile in a polar protic solvent, since the fluoride ion is so heavily solvated (or hydrated) that it loses it’s ability to act as a nucleophile to a large extent. The iodide ion, however, is not solvated effectively because of its huge size and a lesser charge density.

Comment: may I know why is it that "more the s character for an orbital, more is the electronegativity of it"? You have said it as bent's rule, but could you spare sometime for more explanation. The thing I am actually confused about is, people say "more is the size of an atom, the more stable it is to bear a negative charge", but doesn't it counter to say that "$sp$ orbitals which are smallest, can bear a negative charge and be stable compared to $sp^2$ and $sp^3$"?

Comment: The s orbitals are closer to the nucleus than p orbitals, which makes the electron pair in an s orbital more strongly bond. That’s what makes the trend so.

Comment: And I totally understand your point regarding the size of the orbitals. But here’s the thing - electronegativity factor and size factor are giving conflicting suggestions. It just happens to be so, that the electronegative factor is more prominent. I’m not saying size factor is incorrect. It’s just that, considering electronegativity gives a better (in this case the totally opposite) suggestion.

Comment: If I may add this, it’s just one of those things where we can’t quite understand where we went wrong...one thing being more fit than other doesn’t imply the first thing is unreasonable. Because again, I see no fault in your reasoning.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me to understand.

Comment: @AtharvaNavaratne regarding your first message about  Nucleophilicity vs basicity , i have a doubt regarding that .CH3O- is more basic than CH3COO- as the former has a more negative charge density than latter . So ,CH3O - must be more solvated in protic solvent and hence must behave as a weaker nucleophile . But it is the reverse .The nucleophilic character follows the same trend as the basic character in this case . Can you suggest any reason for this ? And what are the other factors except hydration of anion which differentiates nucleophilic character from basic character ?

Comment: @AtharvaNavaratne can you give me an example where to decide basic nature , electronegativity of atom bearing negative charge dominates over the negative charge density ?